# Image Resize in ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, image-resizing

I want resize one image into Multiple Images like thumb_image,Small_image,big_image on One Button click in ASP.NET C#.

Please provide me help or sample code for the same..

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: If you google the same you will get may links. Have you tried one of them?

Comment: yes  @Andrew Barber I tried one but it not working

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```
 var thumbNail = CreateThumbnail(100, 100, fullPath);

        public static Image CreateThumbnail(int maxWidth, int maxHeight, string path)
    {

        var image = Image.FromFile(path);
        var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
        var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
        var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
        var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
        var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);
        var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        image.Dispose();
        return newImage;
    }
```

Comment: All System.Drawing objects must be disposed with a `using` clause, not with .Dispose, as that does not ensure their disposal. The GC does not see System.Drawing instances.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you use a library to do this. There are a lots of code samples, but they're not designed for server side use, whereas [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net) *is*.

At least [read this article on what pitfalls to avoid if you decide to go copy & paste route](http://www.nathanaeljones.com/blog/2009/20-image-resizing-pitfalls).